# .val() don't edit input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Online:**
http://nauka.cf/issue/ui-elements/search-box-1/index.html

**JS (look NUMBER_UP/DOWN ):**
http://nauka.cf/issue/ui-elements/search-box-1/search-box-pc.js

```html
function only_arrows_number(child, arrow_up, arrow_down){
  $(arrow_up).click(function(){
    $(child).val( parseInt($(child).val()) +1 );
    alert($(child).val())
  });

  $(arrow_down).click(function(){
    $(child).val( parseInt($(child).val()) -1 );
    alert($(child).val())
  });
}


only_arrows_number("#adults", "#adults_number_up", "#adults_number_down");
```

**Problem:**

When I click on arrow in ADULTS input, value of this input changing (look alert), but in this input is still value "1".

Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: Get value = `.val()`, edit/set value = `.val("value")`

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it ***in the question itself***. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve)."

Comment: Ok sorry. LShetty - sorry but I dont understand your idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ids with the same name - "adults".
You need to have only one id with this name.

still, you can access the input with this selector:

```
 $('#search-box-adults #adults').val("YOUR VALUE")
```

so your function call should be:

```
only_arrows_number("#search-box-adults #adults", "#adults_number_up", "#adults_number_down");
```